# How do I create the strings file in Xcode like this?

Tags: xcode, localization

This is the current structure of the localizable files in my app:

[image: not wanted]

How do I create a single Localizable file from this that internally has all the translated files, like this:

[image: this is what i want]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You can manage strings files yourself, but the system uses ISO 639 language codes for the localized project (lproj) folders, which can contain more than strings files.

Comment: how do i manage that?

Comment: See Apple's [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html).